# How to do append a character to the end of the first line of a string?

Tags: php

Basically, I am just trying to append a colon to the end of the first line of a string that is meant to represent a small function in python. I already have the logic handled on determining if the colon is at the end of the first line or not, so given that, how would I go about adding a colon to the end of the first line? Here is what the string looks like.

```
<?php
    $input = "def sum(numbers)
    total = 0
    for x in numbers:
        total += x
    return total
print(sum((8, 2, 3, 0, 7)))";

    $firstline = strstr($input,"\n",true);  //retrieve first line

    print($firstline);  //print first line, just for testing
?>
```

I've looked through several functions on w3schools and stuff and found the strstr() function, but this only selects the first line.

One crude (in my opinion) solution I have in mind is possibly retrieving the first line as I do with strstr() and then also getting the rest of the string without the first line, and then concatenating them back together after I edit the first line separately. Would this be the best way of doing this?

Is there any way of selectively editing only the first line of a string in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `preg_replace` we can capture the first line and then replace with a colon added at the end.

```
$input = "def sum(numbers)
total = 0
for x in numbers:
    total += x
return total
print(sum((8, 2, 3, 0, 7)))";

$output = preg_replace("/^(.*?)\n/", "$1:\n", $input);
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
def sum(numbers):
total = 0
for x in numbers:
    total += x
return total
print(sum((8, 2, 3, 0, 7)))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many PHP functions that can help you achieve that: http://php.net/substr_replace , http://php.net/substr , http://php.net/str_replace

```
<?php
    $input = "def sum(numbers)
    total = 0
    for x in numbers:
        total += x
    return total
print(sum((8, 2, 3, 0, 7)))";

    $firstline = strstr($input,"\n",true);  //retrieve first line
    $colon =':';
    $newinput= str_replace($firstline, $firstline.$colon, $input);

    print($newinput); 
?>
```